# Updating a row in a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to find out what the row number is of a button in a grid. I want to save the button row number for later and update it. To update the position of the button I use

```
Grid.SetRow(whatever_button, whatever_row_number);
```

This works fine but it needs to be dynamic. So if the button was originally in row 5, I want to retrieve that value.

In the Google searches there seems to be something called GridView but there is nothing that explains the basic concept of it.

In conclusion:

1.) How do I get buttons row number from a Grid with rows?

2.) What is Gridview?

3.) How do I use Gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get button row number like this:

```
int row = Grid.GetRow(whatever_button);
```

`GridView` represents a view mode that displays data items in columns for a ListView control. More on this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx).

In XAML you can add rows and columns in grid with `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions`. You can add buttons in grid with XAML too.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Button>Button 1</Button>
   <Button Grid.Column="1">Button 2</Button>
   <Button Grid.Column="2">Button 3</Button>
   <Button Grid.Row="1">Button 4</Button>
   <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Button 5</Button>
   <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">Button 6</Button>
   <Button Grid.Row="2">Button 7</Button>
   <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">Button 8</Button>
   <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">Button 9</Button>
</Grid>
```

In C# you can use `Grid.SetRow()` instead of parameter `Grid.Row` in XAML and result is same.

In wpf:`<Button Grid.Row="2" Name="Button7">Button 7</Button>`

In C#: `Grid.SetRow(Button7, 2);`

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped tremendously!